# Retain ActiveSheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

in my code I am copying two rows of cells from one sheet and pasting it another sheet (along with other things that are working properly, so no need to reference it all here). My problem is that I want the macro to do this to every sheet that I choose to run the macro in and not just the sheet that was originally used to record the macro.

```
Sheets("Gr 3 Lang").Select
ActiveCell.Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Gr 3 Math").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

In essence, I don't want it to say "Gr 3 Math" if I intend to run the Macro in "Gr 4 Math" and so on.

I tried using ActiveSheet instead, but at that point "Gr 3 Lang" is the ActiveSheet.

Not sure what to do.

Trenton

Comment: If you use `ActiveSheet` then the code will run in whatever sheet is active. So to run it on "Gr 4 Math", you have to manually select the sheet to make it the Active sheet and then use the code.

Comment: So if you run it in `Gr X Lang` you want the rows pasted into `Gr X Math`?

Comment: @ Rob I - no if I run it in "Gr X Lang" I want it posted in "Gr X Lang". I have sheets for Grades 3-8 both Lang and Math. The first sheet "Gr 3 Lang" has the rows I want pasted into all of the other sheets. So, from Gr 3 Lang it goes to Gr 3 Math to Gr 4 Lang, etc. Obviously, I could just edit the code before running it in each sheet, but I'd like to know how to do it for future reference.

Comment: @user: Where should the copied rows be pasted to in each sheet? If you just use `Activesheet.Paste` then it's going to end up wherever the selection is in that sheet. Might want to review your comment above: at least to me it's still unclear what you really want to do.

Comment: @Tim - Earlier in the code it makes cell A1 the ActiveCell in the sheet. The pasted rows will be pasted at the top. They're header rows that the first sheet has but none of the others do. This is one small part of the code. Doing it by itself, I don't need a macro.
What I am wanting to know is what I should put instead of Sheets("Gr 3 Math").Select to make sure that the rows are pasted into whichever sheet I call the macro from. If I call it from "Gr 4 Math", then I want the rows pasted into "Gr 4 Math" not "Gr 3 Math".

Comment: You don't need to use `.Select` and `.Selection.Copy` just use `.Copy`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
Sheets("Gr 3 Lang").Rows("1:2").Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets(1).Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Replace the 1 with whatever you want. You can use the Sheets("Gr 3 Math") by name or by index.

Comment: That doesn't solve what I'm trying to do. I essentially want the sheets to be a variable. Meaning it will paste into whichever sheet I call the macro from. If I use your code, then if I call it from "Gr 4 Lang" it would paste it into "Gr 3 Math" and not "Gr 4 Lang".